# Understanding food composition data from USDA for Vitamin A

Tags: nutrition

When researching the nutritional value of carrots the Vitamin A comes in two  measurements as RAE and UI:

[image]

https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/11124?n1=%7BQv%3D1%7D&fgcd=&man=&lfacet=&count=&max=25&sort=default&qlookup=Carrots%2C+raw&offset=&format=Abridged&new=&measureby=&ds=&Qv=1&qt=&qp=&qa=&qn=&q=&ing=

After reading the following article 
https://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/VitaminA-HealthProfessional/

I understand that IU can be transferred to RAE, but I wonder if in case of USDA does two records represent the same value or they are supposed to be combined? :shy:

If you had previous experience working with this database I will be more then glad to hear you opinion about that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The corrected answer: It seems that the both rows from your table show the same thing: the sum amount of all vitamin A-related substances, but in different units; the 1st row in RAE and the 2nd row in IU.

As I said before, according to [ods.nih.gov](https://ods.od.nih.gov/factsheets/VitaminA-HealthProfessional/), 1 IU retinol = 0.3 mcg RAE, but this conversation is true only for retinol (the true, "pre-formed" vitamin A), which is found only in animal foods.

The main vitamin A-like substance in plant foods, such as carrots, is beta-carotene and the conversion rate is: 1 IU beta-carotene = 0.05 mcg RAE, so the 20-fold difference between 835 mcg RAE and 16,706 IU now makes sense.

Why to complicate this?

Large amounts of vitamin A (retinol) can be toxic. The upper tolerable level (the amount that should cause no side effects and is not nearly toxic) for retinol for adults is 3,000 mcg RAE. For example, [100 g of chicken liver](https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods/show/05661?fgcd=&manu=&format=&count=&max=25&offset=&sort=default&order=asc&qlookup=liver&ds=&qt=&qp=&qa=&qn=&q=&ing=) contains 4,296 RAE of retinol. (You can also see that for the liver, 4296 RAE/14378 IU = 0.3, so this explains again that the two rows are the same thing.)

You can see that the same IU of vitamin A in animal foods is translated into much more RAE than in plant foods. This is also why high IU of vitamin A in animal foods can be (potentially) much more toxic that the same IU of plant foods.

Comment: @volna, I had to correct my answer entirely....